# WooCommerce: what's the difference between cart total and subtotal?

Tags: woocommerce

I can't find an explanation anywhere in the docs. I also looked at the source code, but it doesn't help, either. Many thanks!

Comment: These are not woocommerce but generic terms used for a shopping cart. the sub total refers to total price of all products in the cart and the cart total is the amount after taxes and shipping. It depends on how a theme will display these details

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm afraid this is not how it works in WooCommerce. In my test store, with taxes enabled, I get "subtotal":127,"subtotal_ex_tax":105.8333, so clearly subtotal includes taxes. These kind of subtleties are exactly what I'm interested in - does one but not the other include tax, shipping, discounts, etc.

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/ this might help. As I said, it depends on how the theme is serving subtotals. A total for a product with multiple quantities can also be a subtotal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OK, I figured it out on my test store with the following settings:

- total prices of products in cart (with taxes): 127
- shipping costs: 12
- fees (taxable): 13
- discount from a coupon: 10

With these settings, I get the following on my cart object:

`"cart_contents_total":97.4998,
"total":144.6,
"subtotal":127,
"subtotal_ex_tax":105.8333,
"tax_total":22.1001,
"discount_cart":8.3334,
"discount_cart_tax":1.6667,
"fee_total":13,
"shipping_total":10,
"shipping_tax_total":2,
"fees":[{"id":"extra-fee", "name":"Extra Fee", "amount":13, "tax_class":"", "taxable":true, "tax":2.6, "tax_data":{"1":2.6}`

So, the answer is:

- total = total prices of products in cart (with tax) + shipping cost + fees + tax on fees - discount
- subtotal = total prices of products in cart (with tax)