# Rename Woocommerce “Place Order” Button if order total is 0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the text of the place order text if the order total is 0 to be something different which is for the free orders.

I tried this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'misha_custom_button_text' );
 
function misha_custom_button_text( $button_text ) {
   return 'Submit'; // new text is here 
}
```

I hope i find a solution
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this code.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_text', 'misha_custom_button_text', 9999);

function misha_custom_button_text($button_text) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $total = $woocommerce->cart->total;
    if ($total == 0) {
        $button_text = "Free Orders";
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and its working but can you tell me which is better yours or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59106247/11217852

Comment: Both answers are the same logic but this is standard code Woocommerce as per Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your function with below and try once if it work for you.

```
function misha_custom_button_text($button_text) {
    $total = WC()->cart->total;

    if ($total == 0) {
        $button_text = "Submit";
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

You can get cart total from `WC()->cart->cart_contents_total` and apply condition whatever you want.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, i will test it out, so its the cart total not the order total right ?

Comment: Yes, you will get order total after you place order, before that you get cart total.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and its working but can you tell me which is better yours or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59106583/11217852

Comment: I think @Praveen Kumar answer is better. There is no difference between WC() & global $woocommerce but, difference is here: $woocommerce->cart->total & WC()->cart->cart_contents_total. For that you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919859/woocommerce-whats-the-difference-between-cart-total-and-subtotal this answer.

Comment: So you think using @Praveen Kumar is much better even in the point of $total = $woocommerce->cart->total; , or use kumar answer but with your WC()->cart->cart_contents_total , sorry not good at backend so i didn't get it

I need it when the order at the end is 0 regardless any thing i want it only when order is 0

Comment: from  $total = $woocommerce->cart->total; or WC()->cart->total any thing you can use, it doesn't matter. Beacuse if you use WC() it will set global like: $GLOBALS['woocommerce'] = wc();. So both are same

Comment: Ok so using kumar answer is better right ? which will calculate the products price + tax when their total is 0 it will change the place order button text to the desired text right ?, and thank you so much for your clarification.

Comment: Yes and I have also updated my answer so it will more clear to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203578/discussion-between-wp-developer-and-maged-mohamed).